# Unable to instal Sys Go package, I tried the normal way but it doesn't make sense. Please find below my Go env below

Tags: linux, go, ubuntu

I cannot get the GoLang Sys package installed.
[image]

Furthermore, below is my Go env:

```
GO111MODULE="auto"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/zahidk/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/zahidk/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/zahidk/gocode/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/zahidk/gocode"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.17.6"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build2915773640=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

I tried using go get -u golang.org/x/sys and GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/sys from the website (https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys#section-readme) to install the sys package but for some reason it doesn't work. Furthermore in my src directory are all my GoLang files. That's it.

Comment: What does “it doesn’t work” mean? Was the module added to your go.mod?

Answer (score 1):

Your `go env` indicates you are using GOPATH mode (instead of modules):

```
GO111MODULE="auto"
GOPATH="/home/zahidk/gocode"
GOMOD=""
```

The error message indicates the editor `GOPATH` is `/home/zahidk/GoLang` which
is different to your `go env` (`/home/zahidk/gocode`). This likely explains why the downloaded code is
not found when developing via the editor.

You should ensure the `GOPATH` environment variable is set correctly everywhere, or migrate to modules.

Using modules is recommended if you don't have a specific need for `GOPATH`. Modules make it easier to manage dependencies and are likely better supported by your editor.

- [Using Go Modules](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules)
- [Getting started with Go](https://play-with-go.dev/get-started-with-go_go115_en/) -- interactive tutorial demonstrating modules in a new project.

Comment: Thanks, yes Go Modules work really well.